# How do I commit my working copy back to my repository without committing the subfolders in my working copy?

Tags: svn

I have a working copy that I checked out from my repository.  Now I want to commit it back to the repository but I don't want the subfolders in my working copy to be committed back any longer.  For example, my working copy file path is Z:\school\ and I don't want Z:\school\2011_2012\ to be committed back.  How would I implement this in a batch file for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Either commit the specific altered files, or use the `--depth` argument:

> --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
>                               'immediates', or 'infinity')

Another option is of course the adding only the files in question to a changelist and commit those with `--changelist`